# Is this propositional logic inference incorrect?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Trying to figure out whether I am applying the rules of propositional logic correctly in the following inference:

[x≠a ∨ x≠b] → [¬(x=a) ∨ ¬(x=b)] → [¬(x=a ∧ x=b)] →X→ [¬(x=a=b)] → [¬(x=a ∧ x=b ∧ a=b)] → [¬(x=a) ∨ ¬(x=b) ∨ ¬(a=b)] → [x≠a ∨ x≠b ∨ a≠b]

My intuition says that the step →X→ is incorrect, but I can't figure out why. It seems like De Morgan's Laws are applied correctly.

When a=1 and b=2 is substituted, the premise [x≠a ∨ x≠b] would then evaluate to 'true', which feels incorrect. Or is it correct after all?

Comment: What do you mean by "→X→"?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps are correct. $$[\neg(x=a\land x=b)]\to[\neg(x=a=b)]\tag1$$ is true for any $a,b,x$.

Suppose by way of contradiction it's false; then, $\neg(x=a\land x=b)$ must be true but $\neg(x=a=b)$ must be false. This means that $x=a\land x=b$ is false but $x=a=b$ true. Since $x=a=b$ is true, we know that $x=a=b\leftrightarrow x=a\land x=b\land a=b$ (*), in particular $x=a\land x=b$ is true, but this contradicts our deduction of $x=a\land x=b$ false. So $(1)$ holds for all $a,b,x$.

(*) Is very easy to see: $\to$ is pretty obvious; for $\leftarrow$ it is because of transitivity of $=$.

---

You could also argue by rule of addition which states $p\to p\lor q\equiv\mathrm{T}$ (do the truth table), so from $x\neq a\lor x\neq b$ you end up with $(x\neq a\lor x\neq b)\lor a\neq b$ and, by associativity of $\lor$, $x\neq a\lor x\neq b\lor a\neq b$. This way saves you a few steps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It was not intuitively clear to me, but then logic is not always necessarily so. It is a very useful inference, since it significantly simplifies the problem I am working on.

Comment: @Ferdinand if the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted